# Number of likes for user

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Is there any way to retrieve the number of times a user hits the like button in a given timeframe on facebook? I am working on a personal analytics app and in terms of facebook activity, I'd like to know how often a user likes/shares on facebook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to achieve this, unless it is only about your own like buttons. In that case, you can subscribe to the `edge.create` event: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/v2.5

Answer (score 0):

Find a way to check activity log and then try find the date of each activity that person on facebook has done, then relate them to each other by specific time that you like and then do the rest by yourself as you like!

Comment: There's no way of accessing the activity log. Or I can't find it

Comment: exactly, there is no way to access the activity log